# Passing a nested structure variable from C++ to a C++ dll causes (L"Buffer is too small" && 0)

Tags: c++, dll

I have structure

```
NewStruct1
{
  uint factor;
  NewStruct2 assert[3];
  char name[21];

}
```

and another

```
NewStruct2 
{
  uint newFactor;
  char newName[21];
}
```

Here I am calling a function 'func' in a dll, as follows

```
NewStruct1 var;

func(&var);
```

The function is

```
func(NewStruct1 *v)
{
  std::string myName = "werttt";
  strcpy_s(v->assert[0].newName, myName.size(), myName.c_str());
}
```

While doing so `strcpy_s` gives `(L"Buffer is too small" && 0)` even though there is enough space to accommodate. Can any body please help me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument of `strcpy_s` must be number of elements in *destination*, that is, 21 (number of chars in in `newName`), not the length of the source.